# C#: add a resource as an attachment to an Outlook mail item

Tags: c#, email, outlook, interop, attachment

I'm trying to attach a file to an email that will be sent in Outlook, in C#.
I've got the following that works great:

```cs
using OutlookApp = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application;
[...]
public class Foo
{
    private void SendMail()
    {
        OutlookApp outlookApp = new OutlookApp();
        MailItem mailItem = outlookApp.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);
        [...]
        var rootDirectory = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath;
        Attachment myAttachment = mailItem.Attachments.Add(Path.Combine(rootDirectory, @"../../Assets/image.png"));
        [...]
        mailItem.Display(false);
    }
}
```

It works, but it sucks a bit because right now my file is in a static folder that won't be there when the project is built.
So I've put my image in the resources of the project: the image is now available via `Properties.Resources.image`.
Naively, I've done the following:

```cs
using OutlookApp = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application;
[...]
public class Foo
{
    private void SendMail()
    {
        OutlookApp outlookApp = new OutlookApp();
        MailItem mailItem = outlookApp.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);
        [...]
        var rootDirectory = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath;
        Attachment myAttachment = mailItem.Attachments.Add(Properties.Resources.image);
        [...]
        mailItem.Display(false);
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Member not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020003 (DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND))'

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.attachments.add.aspx), I read for the first parameter of the `Attachments.Add` method that:

> Type: System.Object
>   The source of the attachment. This can be a file (represented by the full file system path with a file name) or an Outlook item that constitutes the attachment.

The problem, as I understand it, is that I can only provide a file name in order to add an attachment to an Outlook mail. The other option would be to create an Outlook attachment, but if I understand it's not possible. The only way of doing that is by... Adding a file the the attachments of the `mailItem`.
So my questions are the following:

1. is my approach correct to add an attachment? If so, how can I do to get the path of the resource file?
2. if this approach is a good one, is there a way to reference a file elsewhere than the `Resources.resx` file in the projet? Meaning: the file path will be available in my application and the file will be "exported" when I build the project;
3. if my approach is not correct, how can I add an attachment to a `MailItem` from a resource file properly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, in the end I adapted my method.
In the build action for all the images that I needed, I did the following (this is available in the property tab for the file):

- *Build action*: Content.
- *Copy to output directory*: Copy if newer.
  [image: build options]

That way, at build, the folder containing my images (and my images) are copied to the build directory. I can then use their relative URL:

```cs
Attachment myAttachment = mailItem.Attachments.Add(Path.GetFullPath("Assets/image.png"));
```

I don't know if it's the only way to do it, but it works, it doesn't seem ugly and I can still use the images in the XAML. When images are placed in a `resx` file, apparently, it's a PITA.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the resource isn't available as an item to attach. Is there a way to instead save the resource as an image to the computer somewhere and then attach that file you created?

Something like this might work.

```
 var bmp = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.myimage);

 Attachment myAttachment = mailItem.Attachments.Add(bmp);
```

Comment: It didn't seem OK to me to instantiate a new object based on a object that already existed. The "cost" is probably not expensive, but in principle I didn't like that. Still, your solution pushed me to see my problem from another angle, and in the end I found my solution.